# Weird CSS Media Behaviour

Tags: css

I'm creating a responsive web page that switches between different styles depending on the width of the screen.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1279px) 
{ 
  .col-xs-6 {width: 90%;}
}
```

If I open the web page in Chrome, press F12 and toggle the device toolbar I can manually adjust the screen width and see the styles change correctly.

But out of F12 mode, standard desktop view, the above code is being used? Even though my screen size is 1800px and it should be using the default styling:

```
.col-xs-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Long story short: My CSS file is acting as if my screen is less than 1067px but it's not, its 1800px.

Comment: you're missing a closing bracket `}` after `width:90%`.

Comment: Updated the code to reflect the .css file - no brackets missing.

Comment: please post your html page. I would like to test it

Comment: Can you add this to head tag ? 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

Comment: Are you sure the screen is 1800 CSS pixels wide? If you have a phone or a Retina screen, a hardware dot is smaller than a pixel. Also, make sure you're not zoomed in.

Answer (score 1):

Missing pair of brackets?

```
@media (max-width: 1279px) {
.col-xs-6 {
        width: 90%!important;
    } /* this is missing */
}
```

Comment: I wish it was that simple! The first set of brackets don't seem to be displayed in Chrome Dev Tools. I've updated the code above to reflect the actual .css file

Comment: I just can't figure out why my .css file is using @media 1279px when the width of the web page is 1800!

It works perfectly fine inside the device emulator. 

What code would you like to see?

Comment: Did you copy the code I sent you and replaced it? It has a mandatory !important tag which overwrites all CSS.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see why I'd add an !important tag to a style that I DONT wan't to be used?

Comment: I added it anyway just for the sake of it but no difference.

Comment: Gonna have to post your HTML or I can't help further.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the property

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1279px) 
{ 
  .col-xs-6 {width: 90%;}
}
```

to be used for your 1800px screen, you need to put it like

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1279px) 
{ 
  .col-xs-6 {width: 90%;}
}
```

***to apply the same style to  all devices having screen width greater than or equal to 1279px; you can use any size instead of 1279px from where you want the properties to come into effect.***

if you want it to start from 1800px only you can use,

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1800px) 
{ 
  .col-xs-6 {width: 90%;}
}
```